# play video in ios6

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

When the aplicattion starts, the video will run automatically

but pressing the button home and open again the app freezes and do not know why

what can i do?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    m_player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
            [m_player.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
            [m_player.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
            [m_player setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
            [[m_player view] setFrame:[self.view bounds]];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

            [m_player play];
            [self.view addSubview:[m_player view]];
    }


- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)_notification
{

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                              name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                      object:nil];

        [m_player.view removeFromSuperview];
        [m_player stop];
        m_player = nil;

    }

}
```

Comment: So the app is completely frozen or is it just the video that freezes?

Comment: Check the crashlog or if you are connected to xcode, the console and share. Probably that should tell the reason.

Comment: The app and video freezes
and say this

[MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, not enough buffered to keep up.

Answer (score 2):

**This code help me to avoid freezes app when press button home and the video is play and works!!!**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(handleEnteredBackground:)
                                             name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object: nil];




-(void)handleEnteredBackground:(NSNotification*)_notification{

   [m_player play];

}
```